# Setting up MSYS: ./configure is not recognized by Windows 7 as a command

Tags: mingw, msys

I'm following a [tutorial for installing Synthesis Toolkit on Windows 7](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ying/McGill/MUMT618/STK_Windows_MinGW.htm)

I figured that I already installed MinGW and MSYS, and I should be able to skip the steps where he talks about how to install and setup the environment, but I typed all the commands to install:
`gcc g++ mingw32-make gdb msys-base` again just to make sure everything is installed. I got errors saying all the requested packages have been installed. Then I made sure the path environment was set up according to the article.

But when I tried to type in `./configure --enable-debug`, Windows kept saying that `.` is not recognized as a command.

I did some googling and found out that MSYS is the one controlling this type command. So I reinstall both MinGW and MSYS, then set up the Path environment, restart my computer, and follow the tutorial again, but still no luck.

There must be something wrong with MSYS. I don't think I set it up correctly because I only add `C:\MinGW\bin` to the path environment. I didn't do anything to MSYS, but I was using "mingw-get-inst-20120426.exe" to get MinGW and MSYS, I clicked on all the options that I can add to MinGW, I thought MSYS should be set up already after that.

I can't use `.\configure` at all. And I saw other tutorials saying I need to mount MinGW to MSYS by using `mount c:/mingw /mingw`. But `mount` is not recognized by Windows 7 either. I'm thinking MSYS is the problem. There is one tutorial saying to "Set the environment variable `HOME` to `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\home`". So I look into the home folder, and it's empty. So I added `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` to the path environment. It didn't work out.

Answer (score 3):

By checking http://wiki.openttd.org/Compiling_on_Windows_using_MinGW,

I realized that you should first start your msys.bat at ${MinGW_PATH}\msys\1.0\msys.bat( mine is C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat ).

There you can then do whatever you likes to do.

```
./configure
make
make install
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Uhm...I just found that running the msys.bat file directly (open the msys directory and MANUALLY start msys.) works as well.
Once using the Msys console, change directories to the file you are trying to config/install and you can use the "./" prefixed commands there...

So effin annoying....

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, instead of running msys.bat, you can add `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin` to your PATH (environmental variable) and then run `sh` in PowerShell to enter shell and run all commands you need from there.